# How do I assign a class instance method to a variable?

Tags: php, php-5.3

Say I'm here:

```
class Foo
{
    public function test()
    {
        // I'm here!
    }

    private function pow() {}
}
```

I want to declare a local variable that references the method `$this->pow`. I try:

```
$pow = $this->pow;
```

This doesn't work:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Foo::$pow
```

How do I reference a class instance method in PHP?

---

I need this because I need to pass the function to an anonymous function inside `test`. I can't pass `$this` to the anonymous function because I'm using PHP 5.3, and that only became possible in PHP 5.4. Also, the function `pow` is not public, so I can't assign `$this` to an intermediary variable and pass that to the anonymous function.

Comment: You should try [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: At least return a number or string in the pow() function so it does something :)

Comment: pow isn't a property from your code, it's a class method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pow` is `public` as it is in your example, then you can simply do this:

```
$self = $this;
$invokePow = function() use ($self) { $self->pow(); };

// ... some time later ...
$invokePow(); // calls pow()
```

You can also do the same by passing around `array($this, 'pow')` as a [callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) and invoking it with [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

If `pow` is not `public`, you are simply out of luck.

However, if you are able to upgrade to 5.4 then it all becomes much easier:

```
$invokePow = function() { $this->pow(); };
```

You don't need to capture `$this` explicitly, *and* you can invoke `$invokePow` from any context (even outside the class).